# How to access a qml ListElement from c++

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qt5, qt5.9

I have a ListModel:

```
ListModel {
  ListElement {
    property: "value"
  }
  ListElement {
    property: "value2"
  }
}
```

which I am trying to access from a c++ Qt class.

I've managed to get a reference to the listmodel:

```
QQmlEngine engine;
QQmlComponent component(&engine,
            QUrl("qrc:///path.qml"));
QObject *object = component.create();
```

Debbuging the object gives me a `QQmlListModel(adress)`.
`object -> chlidren()` gives me nothing, `object -> children().count()` shows 0. 
 I tried making a `QList` or `QTableView` from the `object`, but with no luck.

How can I get the values of the ListElements ?

Comment: Why do you need it this way? Do you really need whole ListModel or maybe only the value of one element?

Comment: @Xplatforms I've got a ListModel with different ListElements - same properies, but different values. I need a cpp counterpart - for now i populate a QAbstractListModel using invokable methods, but i was wondering if this could be done in the constructor of the class.

Comment: Why do you want to send data from QML to c ++? that is not recommended, if you give us a broader context we could suggest other better solutions.

Comment: Facing such issue means you have an application design problem. C++ implementation of `ListModel` is private and should not be used. Using custom  QAbstractItemModel implementation  could solve the problem.

Comment: I know this is backwards to what it should be. I'm not calling the shots, and I'm not authorized to alter this by much. If this becomes a major issue, rewriting the QML ListModel to a C++ QAbstractionItemModel will be the next course of action, until then, i just wanted to know if i can suck out data from the ListModel, to keep things in one place.

Comment: [`class Q_QML_PRIVATE_EXPORT QQmlListModel : public QAbstractListModel`](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtdeclarative/src/qml/types/qqmllistmodel_p.h.html) => This means you can use the `QAbstractListModel`-API to read out everything you need. Also to alter the content.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As `QQmlListModel` inherits `QAbstractItemModel` you can use all methods provided and implemented by this class.

More specifically you will be looking for:

- [`rowCount()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html#rowCount) to tell you how many `ListItem`s have been added
- [`index(int row, int column, const QModelIndex &parent = QModelIndex())`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html#index) where your column will be `0` at all times.
- [`itemData(const QModelIndex &index)`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html#itemData) to retrieve the data.

Then you can easily iterate over the model.

```
QQmlComponent component(&engine, "MyQmlListModel.qml");
QObject* o = component.create();
QAbstractListModel* m = qobject_cast<QAbstractListModel*>(o);

if (m != nullptr) {
    qDebug() << m->rowCount();
    qDebug() << m->data(m->index(0, 0), 0);
}
else { qDebug() << "failed!"; }
```

Comment: Thanks, however, how can i call these methods on the created *QObject ? I tried casting (QAbstractListModel)object,  qobject_cast<QAbstractListModel>(object), or reinterpret_cast<QAbstractListModel>(object), but all i get is invalid cast errors, or abstract return types. Should I make a new class inheriting from QAbstractListModel, and cast the object on the new class ?

Comment: Yep, you need to use `qobject_cast<QAbstractListModel*>(object)` instead of `qobject_cast<QAbstractListModel>(object)`. It will be a pointer.

Comment: For some reason, I don't know, `itemData` seems to fail. Retrivel via `data` seems to work.